# Скачивание файла

Tags: vb.net, .net

Как оформить прогресс скачивания (хотя бы прогрессбаром), если это требуется еще до того, как загрузилась основная форма(т.е. во время **Form1_Load**). Скачивание осуществляю так:

```
Dim WithEvents wc As New System.Net.WebClient
wc.DownloadFile("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/63791494/A7u/A7u_track.mp3", mp3_name)
```

wc.DownloadFileAsync - не предлагать. Т.к. сразу же после загрузки **Form1** она работает с этим файлом.

Второй вопрос следует из первого - можно ли как-нибудь ускорить загрузку файлов по прямым ссылкам с интернета через Visual Basic .NET?

Как создать диалог выбора пути, куда сохранить скачиваемый данным методом (указан выше) файл? Мне надо, чтобы пользователь сам выбирал место, куда его загрузить. Пока же у меня место фиксированное, т.е. только и прямо в папку с самим исполняемым файлом.

P.S. Работаю в Visual Studio 2010

Comment: А почему "не предлагать" DownloadFileAsync? Вы не разобрались с многопоточным программированием? Обыкновенный DownloadFile тупо блокирует вызывающий поток до тех пор, пока загрузка будет не окончена, и не шлёт при этом сообщений о [прогрессе загрузки](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

1. Поменять стартовую форму и показывать прогрессбар на новой.
2. Есть вероятность, что скачивание в несколько секций ускорит загрузку.
3. SaveFileDialog или FolderBrowserDialog.

Answer (score 0):

1) Для показа прогресса вам придется показывать другую форму во время загрузки основной;

2) Насчет вебклиента смотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351165/download-transfer-speed-slow-when-using-webclient);

3) Диалог выбора пути предоставляется классом System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog.

P.S.: Приведите свой пост в читабельный вид, плз.

Comment: Первый раз пишу тут, не знаю пока еще, как оформлять. Звиняйте.

1) Как мне это сделать?
2) Да нет, в том то и дело, что WebClient как то ограничивает скорость. Тестил на инете 20МБит/с - 6МБ файл качает около 60сек. При том, что браузер(я уж не говорю про Download Manager) скачивает за чуть более, чем 10 сек. На скорости 40МБит/с дела обстоят уже получше, но ограничение все же ощущается. Сервер, с которого качался файл - Dropbox. Тесты проводил по несколько раз, брал среднее арифметическое. Время всех тестов в диапазоне 1 часа.

Comment: 3) Это я знаю. Суть в том, что я уже могу вызвать само диалоговое окно с выбором файла, но вот связать его с тем, чтобы это был выбор именно пути для скачиваемого файла - никак не могу.

Нужны более подробные примеры кода. Или хотя бы конкретный пинок в нужном направлении. Буду благодарен. :)

Comment: 1) Создать форму с прогрессбаром, показать ее перед началом загрузки файла, после завершения загрузки скрыть ее и показать основную форму;
2) Таки имеют место тормоза, добавил ссылку в ответ;
3) В чем проблема? Создайте экземпляр OpenFileDialog, проинициализируйте нужные свойства.

Comment: Не Open, а Save.